# Pass data between refresh/reload (client side, without server side sessions)

Tags: javascript, security, session, reload

In a singlepage application I'd like to pass sensitive data during a page reload/refresh.

Since the data is sensitive it should not be recovered, for example

- when a user leaves the domain and then goes back
- when a user closes the user agent and restarts it, restoring the previous session

History

- thirdpartypage.com *(discard data when moving to here)*
- mypage.com
- thirdpartypage.com *(discard data when moving to here)*

My approach was store it in the `sessionStorage`.

```
// On data generation/update
sessionStorage.setItem("data", "DATA");

// ...

// On load (reload)
var data = sessionStorage.getItem("data")

if (data) {
    // Initialize application with data
} else {
    // Start without
}
```

Unfortunately, in the `sessionStorage` the data persists when moving from my application's domain to a foreign domain (and back or forth to my application's domain).

I also tried storing it in

- `window.name`, but while for Chrome this is acceptable (not persisted across domains), Firefox makes the data accessible at the other domain (IE untested)
- a short-lived cookie but I don't find this solution secure

Comment: Just for clarification, are you protecting against unauthorized access from the same computer, or something else?

Comment: Yes  Schlaus, primarily I'd like to protect against unauthorized access from the same computer. Imagine the user is using this application in a public library and sloppily navigating to another domain instead of loging out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text input that is populated after the page is loaded, on refreshing the page, the browser will repopulate that field with the previous value. If the user leaves the page and comes back to it(not reload), the field will not be repopulated anymore.

So what you could do is to put the ssensitive information in a hidden text input and fetch it from there, it will be there only if the user has refreshed the page.

Comment: Nice pragmatic apporach. Works in Firefox 38, doesn't work in Chrome 42, IE untested yet ([this is what I've tried](http://pastebin.com/25JHzETF)). I think that this behaviour highly depends on non-standardized user agent specific functions (isn't it?), making this approach hard to predict.

Answer (score 0):

There's two distinctively separate issues here to consider:

1. Sensitive data is left on the computer when a user navigates away from the site without logging out, and then later on somebody else visits the site and stumbles on the previous user's data.
2. Someone with access to the same computer is actively trying to get their hands on your data, and goes poking around in the browser's sqlite database.

For the first case it would be enough to somehow differentiate between a page reload and a new visitor. Once you know that, you could just wipe sessionStorage for new visitors. `document.referrer` will tell you if someone is coming in through a link, but it can't tell if somebody typed in the address or if the page was just reloaded. Maybe combined with a short-lived cookie you could come up with a solid strategy.

The second case is more tricky, and I think you'll have to consider if the data in question is **that** sensitive that someone would go to these lengths. One could also argue that the user should have some responsibility for protecting their data as well. One solution could be to store that data in sessionStorage encrypted, and in `window.onbeforeunload` store the key in a short lived cookie. If the cookie still exists when the page is loaded you can decrypt the data and resume session, and if not, purge the storage.

I'm not sure if these methods are acceptable to you, but I'm not aware of a better way to achieve this. That's not to say one does not exist. However, if you do choose to go the encryption way, [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) is my go-to solution for javascript encryption and hashing.

Here's a pseudocode example:

```
global var user

when page loads {
    encryptionKey = getEncryptionCookie()
    if encryptionKey is null {
        // No key found, this is a new user
        eraseSessionStorage()
        user = initNewSession()
    } else {
        // Cookie found
        data = decrypt(getFromStorage('user-data'), encryptionKey)
        if data is valid {
            user = restoreSession(data)
        } else {
            // Wrong key, either an anomaly or a hack attempt
            eraseSessionStorage()
            user = initNewSession()
        }
    }
    user.key = newEncryptionKey()

}

when user does something {
    user.data = getNewData()
    saveToStorage('user-data', encrypt(user.data, user.key))
}

// ie. window.onbeforeunload in JS
when user leaving {
    // the validity has to be long enough to last
    // through a refresh, but short enough so no one
    // can re-enter the site without the user noticing
    setEncryptionCookie(user.key, 10 seconds)
}
```

This way the data is never saved unencrypted, so even if somebody manages to grab it from the sessionStorage it's useless, provided of course that you generate secure keys. Maybe use the mouse position as a seed for a randomizer function?

Comment: Schlaus, `document.referrer` is empty when the user enters the URL or navigates though back/forward buttons, it's only set by `href`s and `location` changes.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I know, it's in my answer. I'll edit in a more concrete suggestion.